# WCF FaultException inconsistency

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

I have a WCF service that throws FaultExceptions when something goes wrong. Some of the error classes being thrown works just fine, yet some of the other doesn't work at all and give the following error:

> An error occured while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost/MyService. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down).

With an inner exception saying

> The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

My code works thusly:

**Server**

```
public Stream DoSomething() {
    if (someCondition) {
        if (fileExists) {
            return new Stream(); // I know I can't do this, but for example purpose only :)
        }
        throw new FaultException<System.IO.FileNotFoundException>(new FileNotFoundException());
    }
    throw new FaultException<MyException>(new MyException());
}
```

**Exception class**

```
public class MyException: Exception
{
}
```

**Client**

```
try {
    wcfClient.DoSomething();
} catch (FaultException<FileNotFoundException>) {
    // This works just fine
} catch (FaultException<MyException>) {
    // This gives the error listed above
}
```

Both FileNotFoundException and MyException are set up in the contract:

```
[FaultContract(typeof(FileNotFoundException))]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyException))]
```

Why does `FaultException<FileNotFoundException>` work as expected, but not `FaultException<MyException>`?

If I remove `Exception` inheritance from `MyException` everything works as it should (but I want consistency, so I want it to be an actual exception). There is no change if `Exception` inheritance is left in, but it is decorated with `[DataContract]`.

Why is that? `FileNotFoundException` inherits from `Exception` too. One works, the other doesn't. Frustrating!

P.S.: Both the server and the client share the same assembly the interfaces and classes are defined in, so there shouldn't be any contract mismatches.

Comment: It would help if you could post the actual code of the exception class that does not work. What does it look like?

Comment: It looks exactly like I've posted (`MyException`). The only difference is the name of the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exception should probably be `[Serializable]`. I think that would solve your problem already.

As a [best practice for Exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/87cdya3t(v=vs.110).aspx) you should also implement the three constructors.

Comment: I got into some other problems when doing that, but at least the original error in the question disappeared, so I'll consider this the answer.